# MVC5 helper htmlAttributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am trying to add htmlAttributes to an existing helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ExCheckBox (this HtmlHelper helper, string name, bool? value, bool readOnly)
{
  return ExCheckBox(helper, name, value, readOnly, "");
}

public static MvcHtmlString ExCheckBox (this HtmlHelper helper, string name, bool? value, bool readOnly, string Label)
{
  var HTML = ExCheckBox(helper, name, value, readOnly, Label, new Dictionary<string, string>());
  return new MvcHtmlString(HTML.ToString());
}

public static MvcHtmlString ExCheckBox4 (this HtmlHelper helper, string name, bool? value, bool readOnly, string Label, object htmlAttributes)
{
  var HTML = ExCheckBox(helper, name, value, readOnly, Label, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), new Dictionary<string, string>());
  return new MvcHtmlString(HTML.ToString());
}

public static MvcHtmlString ExCheckBox (this HtmlHelper helper, string name, object value, bool readOnly, string Label, IDictionary<string, string> Params)
    {
    string HTML = "";
    if (readOnly)
        HTML = String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", name, value == null ? "" : ((bool?)value == true ? "Yes" : "No"));
    else
        {
        string DropDownList = AddEmptyOption(System.Web.Mvc.Html.SelectExtensions.DropDownList(helper, name, GetDropDownListItems(value == null ? "" : value.ToString())).ToString());
        HTML += DropDownList;
        }
    HTML = AddCellsAndLabel(HTML, name, Label, Params);
    return new MvcHtmlString(HTML);
    }

public static List<SelectListItem> GetDropDownListItems (string currentValue)
    {
    var list = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var item = new SelectListItem();

    item.Text = "No";
    item.Value = "false";
    if (currentValue == false.ToString())
        item.Selected = true;
    list.Add(item);
    item = new SelectListItem();
    item.Text = "Yes";
    item.Value = "true";
    if (currentValue == true.ToString())
        item.Selected = true;
    list.Add(item);

    return list;
    }

   private static string AddCellsAndLabel (string ControlHTML, string name, string Label, IDictionary<string, string> Params)
            {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Label))
                {
                string ControlColSpan = "";
                string LabelColSpan = "";
                if (Params.ContainsKey(HtmlHelperParams.ControlColSpan))
                    {
                    ControlColSpan = "colspan='" + Params[HtmlHelperParams.ControlColSpan] + "'";
                    }
                if (Params.ContainsKey(HtmlHelperParams.LabelColSpan))
                    {
                    LabelColSpan = "colspan='" + Params[HtmlHelperParams.LabelColSpan] + "'";
                    }
                ControlHTML = String.Format("<td " + LabelColSpan + "  class=\"Label\"><label for=\"{0}\">{1}</label></td>", name, Label) + "<td " + ControlColSpan + " class=\"ControlCell\">" + ControlHTML + "</td>";
                }
            return ControlHTML;
            }
```

The first two helpers work well, the third ExCheckBox4 I get this error:

> No overload for method 'ExCheckBox' takes 7 arguments

I would appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: The error message should be obvious. The 3rd method calls ExCheckBox with 7 arguments. You need another helper which accepts 7 arguments

Comment: Do you even have a method that actually renders any html?

Comment: I use the following:
   @Html.ExCheckBox2("Rotates", Model.Client.Rotates, (bool)this.ViewData["ReadOnly"], " ")

Comment: No I mean all you have shown here is a series of `ExCheckBox()` helper methods that call other overloads of `ExCheckBox()`, but nothing you have shown actually returns any html. What is `ExCheckBox()` actually supposed to be doing?

Comment: Just added it to the question.  As you can tell, I don't have much experience with helpers.

Comment: No kidding :). Can you edit your answer to explain exactly what you want to render, based on what conditions and I'll help you fix this. It does not make much sense, but you appear to want a label which has the text "Yes" or "No" or an empty string (whats the point of that?), OR a dropdown that contains options for "Yes" and "No" (true/false), followed by something rendered by `AddCellsAndLabel()` but you have not included that method)

Comment: You are correct, this helper is for a dropdownlist with three options, empty, yes, and no.   Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65408/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-hncl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a number of problems including

1. It not strongly typed
2. Your overriding the controls name attribute so it wont bind to your
   model on post back
3. Your using this in a table so assuming this is rendered in a `for`
   loop, your rendering duplicate `id` (invalid html) and `name`
   attributes (wont bind to your collection on post back).
4. Your rendering `<label>` elements when its read only but its not
   associated with a control (semantically incorrect).
5. Your extension accepts typeof `object` for the value but will throw
   an exception if its not `nullable bool`

Try the following

```
public static MvcHtmlString XCheckBox<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool?>> expression, bool isReadOnly, int labelColumns, int controlColumns, object htmlAttributes)
{
  ModelMetadata metaData = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData);
  string label = metaData.GetDisplayName();
  string name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
  StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();      
  if (isReadOnly)
  {
    html.Append(ReadonlyLabelCell(label, labelColumns));
    html.Append(ReadonlyValueCell((bool?)metaData.Model, controlColumns));
  }
  else
  {
    html.Append(LabelCell(label, name, labelColumns));
    html.Append(ControlCell(name, (bool?)metaData.Model, controlColumns, htmlAttributes));
  }     
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(html.ToString());
}

private static string ReadonlyLabelCell(string label, int colSpan)
{
  TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
  span.InnerHtml = label;
  TagBuilder cell = new TagBuilder("td");
  cell.AddCssClass("label");
  cell.MergeAttribute("colspan", colSpan.ToString());
  cell.InnerHtml = span.ToString();
  return cell.ToString();
}

private static string ReadonlyValueCell(bool? value, int colSpan)
{
  TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
  span.InnerHtml = value.HasValue ? value.Value ? "Yes" : "No" : "Not set";
  TagBuilder cell = new TagBuilder("td");
  cell.AddCssClass("readonly"); // added class for styling
  cell.MergeAttribute("colspan", colSpan.ToString());
  cell.InnerHtml = span.ToString();
  return cell.ToString();
}

private static string LabelCell(string labelText, string controlName, int colSpan)
{
  TagBuilder label = new TagBuilder("label");
  label.MergeAttribute("for", controlName);
  label.InnerHtml = labelText;
  TagBuilder cell = new TagBuilder("td");
  cell.AddCssClass("label");
  cell.MergeAttribute("colspan", colSpan.ToString());
  cell.InnerHtml = label.ToString();
  return cell.ToString();
}

private static string ControlCell(string controlName, bool? value, int colSpan, object htmlAttributes)
{
  StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
  TagBuilder option = new TagBuilder("option");
  option.MergeAttribute("value", string.Empty);
  option.InnerHtml = "Not set";
  html.Append(option.ToString());
  option = new TagBuilder("option");
  option.MergeAttribute("value", "true");
  if (value.HasValue && value.Value)
  {
    option.MergeAttribute("selected", "selected");
  }
  option.InnerHtml = "Yes";
  html.Append(option.ToString());
  option = new TagBuilder("option");
  option.MergeAttribute("value", "false");
  if (value.HasValue && !value.Value)
  {
    option.MergeAttribute("selected", "selected");
  }
  option.InnerHtml = "No";
  html.Append(option.ToString());
  TagBuilder select = new TagBuilder("select");
  select.MergeAttribute("name", controlName);
  select.MergeAttribute("id", HtmlHelper.GenerateIdFromName(controlName));
  select.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
  select.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
  TagBuilder cell = new TagBuilder("td");
  cell.AddCssClass("controlcell");
  cell.MergeAttribute("colspan", colSpan.ToString());
  cell.InnerHtml = select.ToString();
  return cell.ToString();
}
```

Then for the other overloads

```
public static MvcHtmlString XCheckBox<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, bool?>> expression, bool isReadOnly)
{
  return XCheckBox(helper, expression, isReadOnly, 1, 1, null);
}
```

etc.

And use as follows

```
@Html.XCheckBoxFor(m => m.Client.Rotates, false, 1, 1, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious
There is not method accepting this arguments (in ExCheckBox4 body)

```
var HTML = ExCheckBox(helper, name, value, readOnly, Label, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes), new Dictionary<string, string>());
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change that to

```
public static MvcHtmlString ExCheckBox4 (this HtmlHelper helper, string name, bool? value, bool readOnly, string Label, object htmlAttributes)
{
 var HTML = helper.ExCheckBox(name, value, readOnly, Label, new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
 return new MvcHtmlString(HTML.ToString());
}
```